# Spring Boot config Client | Rest End Point not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-config

I was trying to externalize the configurations through spring boot config server.

I am using SVN as version  control for configurations.

https://svnret2.uk.fid-intl.com:18081/svn/Test_Config/trunk/dev/myapp/myapp-dev.properties

Config server is up an running on port 8888.
----------application.properties for config server----------

```
server.port = 8888
management.security.enabled=false  
endpoints.health.sensitive: false       
spring.profiles.include: subversion  
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap: true  
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.uri: https://svnret2.uk.fid-intl.com:18081/svn/Test_Config/  
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.label: trunk  
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.searchPaths: dev/myapp  
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.username: *****  
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.password: *****
```

To consume the properties from config server ,  I have created spring config client with following configuration in application.properties

----------application.properties---------

```
server.port = 8081 
management.security.enabled=false  
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

There is one rest end point exposed in config client  as below:
---------- Rest End Point----------

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Value("${TestMessage}")
    private String message;

    @RequestMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Message :" + message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

-----------------------------Execution Step--------------------
Run as -> Run Configuration
Arguments
   -Dspring.application.name=myapp
   -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Client is up and running on port 8081. But i am getting 404 while accessing  http://localhost:8081/message

Comment: This has nothing to do with config server or client. The problem is just with your client project. when you start the application do you see the rest mappings(/message) listed in the logs?

Comment: Yes I can see that in the logs

Comment: do you have some context path set in your application. what do you see if you try to reach http://localhost:8081/

Comment: @pvpkiran, No, I have not set any context path.When i try to connect to localhost:8081 I am getting 404 (might be index.html is not existing). I tried to set the context path in application.properties server.contextPath=/configclient but still same issue.

Comment: @pvpkiran , Also , I can access the end point once I remove the VM arguments and Value annotation in MessageController

Comment: it is difficult to comment without seein the whole project. Can you upload the project somewhere and give me access

Comment: I had the same issue, my root package (where main class resides) and the controller package were different. It got resolved when i changed it. Hope this helps.